# Best way to keep map of K String to a string?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have to create a map of N elements, i.e. N elements mapping to  a string . The value of N is not defined at compile time but at run time. Is there some standard way to do so? Currently I am trying to store a map of a class X with string where X is having array of string but that does not seems to be right to me .

Comment: You want a `std::map<sometype, string>`, where sometype is the type of the elements that map to the strings.

Comment: yes svinja  thats what i am currently doing using class X . This seems to be clumpsy for me . Any other option please

Comment: I'm confused, does `N` refer to the *number* of elements that map to a particular string or to the *type* of an element which maps to a string?

Comment: N referes to the number of strings

Comment: In which case is there anything wrong with just using a `std::map<Key, Value>` and inserting multiple keys with the same value since only the keys have to be unique, not the values. Or is it that the multiple keys *must* refer to the same instance of the value object and not just an equivalent one?

Comment: N different keys combine to make 1 key & value pair

Answer (score 3):

you may use `std::map<std::set<std::string>, std::string>`

Look at example:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef std::set<std::string> key_t;
    std::map<key_t, std::string> m;
    m[{"a", "b", "c"}] = "Hello,";
    m[{"d", "e"}] = "world!";
    m[{"f"}] = "\n";
    std::cout << m[{"a", "b", "c"}] << m[{"d", "e"}] << m[{"f"}];
}
```

Please, compile with c++11 enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** In the title it says "K strings to string", however in the body the OP merely speaks of *elements*. So I posted a general approach for various, unspecific elements.

---

Here is a sketch for what you seem to want to achieve:

```
struct some_key
{
    int a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    std::string c;
    std::vector<int> d;
    // ... and so on

    bool operator<(some_key const& rhs) const
    {
        return std::tie(a,b,c,d)<std::tie(rhs.a,rhs.b,rhs.c,rhs.d);
    }
};

int main()
{
    some_key key1;
    some_key key2;
    key2.a=1;

    std::map<some_key, std::string> m;
    m[key1] = "hi";
    m[key2] = "goodbye";

    std::cout<<m[key1]<<std::endl;   //prints "hi"
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b46f37670b0cb509)

With this you can fill the `some_key` class appropriately and use it in the map.